# Compute (Aᵀ×A)*(Bᵀ×B) matrix using gsl, Blas and Lapack

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, lapack, blas, gsl

Let I have 2 symmetric matrices:

```
A = {{1,2}, {2,3}}
B = {{2,3},{3,4}}
```

Can I compute the matrix (A<sup>T</sup>×A)*(B<sup>T</sup>×B) using gsl, Blas and Lapack?

I'm using

```
gsl_blas_dsyrk(CblasUpper, CblasTrans, 1.0, A, 0.0, ATA);
gsl_blas_dsyrk(CblasUpper, CblasTrans, 1.0, B, 0.0, BTB);
gsl_blas_dsymm(CblasLeft, CblasUpper, 1.0, ATA, BTB, 0.0, ATABTB); // It doesn't work
```

It returns:

```
(Aᵀ·A) = ATA = {{5, 8}, {0, 13}} -- ok, gsl_blas_dsyrk returns symmetric matrix as upper triangular matrix.
(Bᵀ·B) = BTB = {{13, 8}, {0, 25}} -- ok.
(Aᵀ·A)·(Bᵀ·B) = ATABTB = {{65, 290}, {104, 469}} -- it's wrong.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Symmetrize BTB and the problem will be solved.**

As you noticed, the upper triangular parts of symmetric matrices are computed by `dsyrk()`. Then `dsymm()` is applied. According to the definition of [`dsymm()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/db0/dsymm_8f.html), the following operation is performed since the flag [`CblasLeft`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Level-3-GSL-BLAS-Interface.html) is used:

```
C := alpha*A*B + beta*C
```

> where alpha and beta are scalars,  A is a symmetric matrix and  B and
>    C are  m by n matrices.

Indeed, **the B matrix is a general matrix**, not necessarly a symmetric one. As a result, **ATA is multiplied by the upper triangular part of BTB**, since the lower triangular part of BTB is not computed.

**Symmetrize BTB and the problem will be solved.** To do so, for loops is a straightforward solution , see [Convert symmetric matrix between packed and full storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445648/convert-symmetric-matrix-between-packed-and-full-storage)