# What is the best data structure for representing an upper triangular matrix in Java?

Tags: java, sparse-matrix

Suppose an upper triangular matrix of integers is given. What's the best way of storing this in Java? The naive 2d int array is obviously not efficient. The solution I came up with was moved to the answers section.

Comment: "Best" in which way? Flexibility? Use one of the existing matrix libraries. Performance? Use a plain 1D array. (If performance is really critical and the matrix is "small", you may even consider creating a (rows*cols) array and leaving the lower left of it empty). In any case, I'd stay away from classes that are not intended to be used as a matrix (like "Tables"), or from nested data structures like lists-in-lists. Also note that for the last bit of performance (even when using an array), the *access pattern* is crucial as well, and whether you use row-major or column-major storage

Comment: You can answer your own question: move your solution to an answer (type it in the "Your Answer" box in this page).

Comment: @PeterO. Thanks. Just moved it to the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Here is my solution: Assume you have a 4X4 upper triangular matrix M.

```
1 2 3 4
0 6 7 1
0 0 8 9
0 0 0 5
```

If you can map every element of M in a 1d array, that's the best solution. All you need to know is to know which [row,col] of matrix corresponds to which element of your 1d array. Here is how you do the magic:

```
start_index=((col_index-1)+1)+((col_index-2)+1)+...+1
end_index=start_index + col_index
```

For example: if I want to find where are the elements on the 3rd column of the matrix, in the array:

```
start_index=((3-1)+1)+((3-2)+1)+((3-3)+1)=6
end_index=6+3=9
```

So, all I need to do is to start at index 6 of my array, and read all the elements till index 9 (including 9th element). Following this procedure, then you can store and retrieve all the cells of the nXn matrix in (n + n^2)/2 space.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to save memory, your solution looks great - it's called a [packed storage matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packed_storage_matrix). Column by column, top down, your array would look like this: `1 2 6 3 7 8 4 1 9 5`

I would suggest a simpler calculation of your indices, based on the sum formula `(n² + n) / 2` (*row* and *column* is zero based).

```
list_index = (column^2 + column) / 2 + row;
```

An implementation could look like the following:

```
public class TriangularMatrix {
    private final int[] list;

    public TriangularMatrix(int size) {
        list = new int[sumFormula(size)];
    }

    public int set(int row, int column, int value) {
        validateArguments(row, column);

        int listIndex = getListIndex(row, column);
        int oldValue = list[listIndex];
        list[listIndex] = value;

        return oldValue;
    }

    public int get(int row, int column) {
        validateArguments(row, column);

        return list[getListIndex(row, column)];
    }

    private void validateArguments(int row, int column) {
        if (row > column) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Row (" + row + " given) has to be smaller or equal than column (" + column + " given)!");
        }
    }

    private int getListIndex(int row, int column) {
        return sumFormula(column) + row;
    }

    private int sumFormula(int i) {
        return (i*i + i) / 2;
    }
}
```

There is [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941678/lapack-are-operations-on-packed-storage-matrices-faster) discussing the (negative) performance impact, although it's about Fortran.

Comment: I worked out a solution for the upper triangular matrix case which was what I needed. please have a look and let me know hat you think.

Comment: @user3639557 I changed my answer to match your question - my first version simply wasn't efficient for triangular matrices.

Answer (score 2):

If the matrix is always diagonal, I would use:

```
List<List<Integer>> matrix = ...
```

If it is an sparse matrix, I would use maps:

```
Map<Map<Integer>> = ...
```

In this second case, you may need to wrap the map in a class with get and set operations in order to manage access to new rows and columns.

All this, however depends on your needs, your memory limites and matrix size.

Comment: I worked out another solution. please have a look and let me know hat you think.

Comment: @user3639557 If yout matrix is always triangular then your solution is right and optimal concerning memory usage. I recommend you to implement its wrapping class with its accesors methods providing a direct access to its elements based on a (i row,j column) index.

Answer (score 2):

What about Guava's [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)? It is implemented using HashMaps or TreeMaps (as well as 2D array if required), but it offers much nicer API than defining a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, V>>`.